# What organisms are Chloroperoxidase enzymes found in?

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology, enzymes

Are they found in humans? I'm wondering because they display a structural similarity to glucose-6-phosphatase, which is an important enzyme in gluconeogenesis.

Comment: Could you add some details of the structural similarity - from a quick search, I see that chloroperoxidases has a 3-layer sandwich (alpha-beta hydrolase) fold and G6P has a number of subunits.

Comment: I can look for more on that but my primary question is what organisms they are found in.

Comment: A good start is to look for the EC in RCSB  : http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/results/results.do?tabtoshow=Current&qrid=2F987A5C there's an 'organism' box on the left hand side

Answer (score 2):

It is only found in an ascomycetes which is named ***Leptoxyphium fumago***, also known as ***Caldariomyces fumago***.

It isn't found in any other specie that we know of yet as searched on the RCSB PDB and Uni-Prot.

In researches that uses it they extract it from the organism, it is also available to buy from companies like Sigma Aldrich who extract it from the ascomycete too.

Sources:

[Improvement of activity and stability of chloroperoxidase by chemical modification](http://bmcbiotechnol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1472-6750-7-23)

[Over-expression of chloroperoxidase in Caldariomyces fumago.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21735258)

[RCSB Protein Data Bank](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/results/results.do?tabtoshow=Current&qrid=2F987A5C)

[Uni-Prot](http://www.uniprot.org/)